# Huffman compression doesn't result in less bytes saving storing tree and pad with coded 0's and 1's

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation, huffman-code

I'm working on implementing a lossless compression algorithm called Huffman Coding in Swift. I started with a version that used Strings of `"1"`'s and `"0"`'s but then learned that a single string for example `"0"` takes a whole byte itself. So I've now converted my string into `[UInt8]` (see `packBits` func). It seems some people approach it with writing a BitWriter and BitReader which I could eventually refactor to, but I think my approach at least gets the same `[UInt8]` results in the end and this definitely cuts down on the size of `HuffData.code` vs text bytes, *however* I need to store the tree to traverse as well as a pad for decoding. Since `encode` func returns `HuffData`, a struct that contains all three, I noticed that the size is actually larger than text I pass to encode.

For example a `paragraph.utf8.count` that equals 8959 bytes, encodes to a total data of about 21099 bytes! 2763 of this is the tree, 5050 is the code and 2 is the pad. The remaining I assume is from the struct? Why don't these add up?

```
let huff = try? Huffman.encode(paragraph)
```

`huff.count` = total data bytes

I'm looking to understand why these byte counts don't add up and what in my code is causing the total to be significantly larger than the text. Do just I need to work with much larger text to see a real result? Can I store tree, code and pad in a more memory efficient way? Why does the total not equal tree + code + pad? Does serializing the data add more bytes? Thanks for the advice!

```
import Foundation

struct HuffData: Codable {
    var code: [UInt8]
    var tree: Node
    var pad: Int
}

class Huffman {
    static func decode(_ data: Data) throws -> String {
        let huff = try JSONDecoder().decode(HuffData.self, from: data)
        var bits: String = ""
        // return bits to a string O and 1
        for i in huff.code {
            var str = String(i, radix: 2)
            // if bits originally started with zeros, that was removed e.g. 32
            if str.count < 8 {
                str = String(repeating: "0", count: 8 - str.count) + str
            }
            bits += str
        }
        return Huffman.traverse(tree: huff.tree, with: String(bits.dropLast(huff.pad)))
    }

    static func encode(_ input: String) throws -> Data {
        // count letter frequency
        let sortedFrequency = input.reduce(into: [String: Int](), { freq, char in
            freq[String(char), default: 0] += 1
        })
        // create queue of initial Nodes
        let queue = sortedFrequency.map{ Node(name: $0.key, value: $0.value)}
        // create tree
        let tree = Huffman.createTree(with: queue)
        // generate key by traversing tree
        let key = Huffman.generateKey(for: tree, prefix: "")
        // bit packed code
        let code = input.compactMap({key[String($0)]}).joined()
        let buffer = Huffman.packBits(for: code)
        // save data
        let huff = HuffData(code: buffer.code, tree: tree, pad: buffer.pad)
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(huff)
        return data
    }

    static private func generateKey(for node: Node, prefix: String) -> [String: String] {
        var key = [String: String]()
        if let left = node.left, let right = node.right {
            key.merge(generateKey(for: left, prefix: prefix + "0"), uniquingKeysWith: {current,_ in current})
            key.merge(generateKey(for: right, prefix: prefix + "1"), uniquingKeysWith: {current,_ in current})
        }else {
            key[node.name] = prefix
        }
        return key
    }

    static private func createTree(with queue: [Node]) -> Node {
        // initialize queue that sorts by decreasing count
        var queue = PriorityQueue(queue: queue)
        // until we have 1 root node, join subtrees of least frequency
        while queue.count > 1 {
            let node1 = queue.dequeue()
            let node2 = queue.dequeue()
            let rootNode = Huffman.createRoot(with: node1, and: node2)
            queue.enqueue(node: rootNode)
        }
        return queue.queue[0]
    }

    static private func traverse(tree: Node, with code: String) -> String {
        var result = ""
        var node = tree
        for bit in code {
            if bit == "0", let left = node.left {
                node = left
            } else if bit == "1", let right = node.right {
                node = right
            }
            if node.left == nil && node.right == nil {
                result += node.name
                node = tree
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    static private func createRoot(with first: Node, and second: Node) -> Node {
        return Node(name: "\(first.name)\(second.name)", value: first.value + second.value, left: first, right: second)
    }

    static private func packBits(for s: String) -> (pad: Int, code: [UInt8]) {
        var result = [UInt8]()
        // pad with extra "0"'s to a length that is exact multiple of 8
        let padding = 8 - (s.count % 8)
        var bits = s + String(repeating: "0", count: padding)
        // convert 8 bits at a time to a byte
        while !bits.isEmpty {
            result.append(UInt8(bits.prefix(8), radix: 2)!)
            bits = String(bits.dropFirst(8))
        }
        return (pad: padding, code: result)
    }
}

struct PriorityQueue {
    var queue: [Node]
    var count: Int {
        return queue.count
    }
    mutating func enqueue(node: Node) {
        queue.insert(node, at: queue.index(where: {$0.value <= node.value}) ?? 0)
    }
    mutating func dequeue() -> Node {
        return queue.removeLast()
    }
    init(queue: [Node]){
        // assumes queue will always be sorted by decreasing count
        self.queue = queue.sorted(by: {$0.value > $1.value})
    }
}

class Node: CustomStringConvertible, Codable {
    var description: String {
        return "\(name): \(value)"
    }
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    let left: Node?
    let right: Node?

    init(name: String, value: Int, left: Node? = nil, right: Node? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    }
}
```

Comment: Huffman encoding can certainly end up being larger than the original data. Don’t forget to divide your encoded size by 8 since you are storing bytes instead of bits, which Huffman is meant to do.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano am I just calculating it wrong? This is how I was calculating. `paragraph.utf8.count` = total paragraph in bytes. `let huff = try? Huffman.encode(paragraph)` and then `huff.count` = total data bytes.

Comment: Might I suggest that you start with a known working implementation and then work backwards so that you understand what is going on? Here is a huffman encoder and decoder that runs on top of Metal. https://github.com/mdejong/MetalHuffman

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding a sequence of bits using one Uint8 = 1 byte = 8 bits per bit. So your "compression" is a factor 8 worse than needed.

First create a data structure that can store 8 bits per byte.

Comment: Can you clarify? I thought that `UInt8` can store a total of 8 `0`'s and `1`'s so 1 `UInt8` = 1 byte.